# Get distinct rows by creation date

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am working with a dataframe like this:

```
DeviceNumber        | CreationDate       | Name
1001                | 1.1.2018           | Testdevice
1001                | 30.06.2019         | Device
1002                | 1.1.2019           | Lamp
```

I am using databricks and pyspark to do the ETL process. How can I reduce the dataframe in a way that I will only have a single row per "DeviceNumber" and that this will be the row with the highest "CreationDate"? In this example I want the result to look like this:

```
DeviceNumber        | CreationDate       | Name
1001                | 30.06.2019         | Device
1002                | 1.1.2019           | Lamp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a additional dataframe with DeviceNumber & it's latest/max CreationDate.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf

max_df = df\
    .groupBy('DeviceNumber')\
    .agg(psf.max('CreationDate').alias('max_CreationDate'))
```

and then join `max_df`  with original dataframe.

```
joining_condition = [ df.DeviceNumber == max_df.DeviceNumber, df.CreationDate == max_df.max_CreationDate ]

df.join(max_df,joining_condition,'left_semi').show()
```

`left_semi` join is useful when you want second dataframe as lookup and does need any column from second dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PySpark windowing functionality:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

# make sure that creation is a date data-type
df = df.withColumn('CreationDate', f.to_timestamp('CreationDate', format='dd.MM.yyyy'))

# partition on device and get a row number by (descending) date
win = Window.partitionBy('DeviceNumber').orderBy(f.col('CreationDate').desc())
df = df.withColumn('rownum', f.row_number().over(win))

# finally take the first row in each group
df.filter(df['rownum']==1).select('DeviceNumber', 'CreationDate', 'Name').show()

------------+------------+------+
|DeviceNumber|CreationDate|  Name|
+------------+------------+------+
|        1002|  2019-01-01|  Lamp|
|        1001|  2019-06-30|Device|
+------------+------------+------+
```